# Is it possible to run database in Oracle VM Virtualbox and use it as database server from your own computer

Tags: virtualbox

I want have Linux based database server. Is it possible to connect from computer that is running Oracle VM Virtualbox to OS running inside virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to connect to your VirtualBox VM from the machine that is running the VirtualBox hypervisor? Sure.  You can even connect to it from other machines on your network (by using a bridged-mode virtual network adapter).
The VirtualBox manual tells you how to do this in far greater detail than I can remember off the top of my head.

How will the performance be if you try to run a database with any kind of load in a VM?  Bloody awful.
Don't use this configuration for anything except possibly development work.

Comment: This is what I meant. I need to use it for development, not for production.

Comment: Honestly, if you can dedicate a core or two to the VM performance should not be that bad. Naturally, if you want to run in production you better not be storing your database off a virtual disk. You should use a SAN or directly connect the raw disk device to the VM. I know virtualbox can do this with USB devices. If you were using VMWare you should have more options.